# How to add items to a QML Grid after creation?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I've done a bit of searching but I've failed to find an answer which must be so simple it hasn't warranted a question thus far.
Anyway I'm new to QML and struggling to find a way to add items to a Grid dynamically post-creation.

Basically I have a Flickable with a Grid inside it containing (by default) four instances of a custom class named ImageTile, and when the MouseArea detects there's a click it wants to add 2 instances of ImageTile to that grid.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
Flickable {
    anchors.fill: parent
    contentWidth: 400
    contentHeight: 800
    clip: true

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onclicked: { /* ADD TWO ImageTile TO imageGrid */ }
    }

    Grid {
        id: imageGrid
        columns: 2
        spacing: 2

        Repeater {
            model: 4
            ImageTile { }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm wondering what I should put inside the onClicked event to achieve adding two new instances of ImageTile to imageGrid.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: A Repeater expects [one of the supported model types](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#qml-data-models).  Using an integer instead makes no sense at all!

Comment: @MrEricSir Oh. I was just making edits to what I saw in official Qt documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-repeater.html

Comment: That's a silly hack that they added for demonstration purposes. In the real world, your model will have data associated with it (like a title, link, image, etc.)  The way you add, remove, or modify what will be shown in your Repeater is by altering the model -- this follows the classic [Model View Controller architecture.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)  Exactly how that model is changed depends on which one you're using.

Comment: @MrEricSir I see. The issue is here I need this grid to contain these QML objects since they need to be interactive. Unfortunately I can't seem to place QML objects as properties for the Data Models that Qt provides. What are my options for populating this grid dynamically after creation with custom objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So thanks to being pushed in the right direction by MrEricSir I've figured the issue out.

First I had to specify a proper Data Model for the Repeater to use, and then assign a delegate function to convert information in the data model to actual QML elements. Appending to the data model automatically triggered the Repeater to execute the delegate function.

```
Flickable {
    anchors.fill: parent
    contentWidth: 400
    contentHeight: 800
    clip: true

    ListModel {
        id: imageModel

        ListElement { _id: "tile0" }
        ListElement { _id: "tile1" }
        ListElement { _id: "tile2" }
        ListElement { _id: "tile3" }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onclicked: {
            imageModel.append({ _id: "tile" + imageModel.count })
        }
    }

    Grid {
        id: imageGrid
        columns: 2
        spacing: 2

        Repeater {
            model: imageModel
            delegate: ImageTile { id: _id }
        }
    }
}
```